# Angularjs ng-repeat doesn't show duplicate values in the list, but only the different ones

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-lists

This code displays the contents of the text box in a list, via the ng-repeat directive.
But I noticed that it doesn't show the duplicate letters.
The letters are only shown if they are all different.
For example, if I type abcabc in the text box, I see abc only once in the list, and not abcabc
How can I also show duplicate letters?
Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="names">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show picture of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever something breaks like this, always check the console. You get errors there because AngularJS expects all values to be unique. But obviously, they aren't. You can use [`track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) to give the elements a unique identifier, in this case I used `track by $index` to make them use their index in the string.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input type="text" ng-model="names">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do It, simply because ng-repeat directive expects all values to be unique.
The solution proposed by using track by $index is the best workaround